# Influence button layout according to screen orientation, without separate layout files

Tags: android

Is there a way to influence the button widget layout according to screen orientation without adding an extra layout for each orientation?

For instance
 **portrait**:

```
<android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon" />
```

and **landscape**:

```
<android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract that attribute and add a style for the button

```
<android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/title"
        style="@style/yourbuttonstyle" />
```

and then create two different style files, one in `res/values` and one in `res/values-land`, using the normal resource folder qualifiers. They could look like this:

*res/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="yourbuttonstyle">
        <item name="android:drawableTop">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

*res/values-land/styles.xml*

```
<style name="yourbuttonstyle">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

See [defining styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles) for more documentation how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to add a separate layout for each orientation (although that is **recommended**), you can do it from code:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
}
else {
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icon, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: In above case you have to override onCnfigurationChanged of your Activity and put this code in there

Comment: @ingsaurabh uhm, no you don't. You can do it in `onCreate()` just as well.

Comment: of course it can be done in onCreate but incase device is rotated and the OP doesnt want to restart the activity.

Comment: Well, first of all, the OP didn't mention anything about that. Second of all, doing that is [discouraged](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the button to portrait/landscape layouts, and keep the main layout orientation-less by [using the `include` directive](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html). So your main layout is not duplicated, only the small button fragments.

This way your main layout is in res/layout, referencing the button layouts (provided in res/layout-<orientation>).